# 3D pendulum with friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, drag

I'm trying to do a simulation of a spherical pendulum of length $l$ with air drag and I need to solve numerically the second order differential equations of the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$, where $\theta$ is the polar angle and $\phi$ is the azimuth angle of the spherical coordinates like the following figure.

[image]

The only forces of the system are the mass reaction and gravity, so my idea was to use the classical equation for the simple pendulum in $\theta$ with speed dipended friction
\begin{equation}
     \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta-\frac{\gamma}{m}\frac{d\theta}{dt}
\end{equation}
where $\gamma$ is the drag coefficient, and only the drag part for $\phi$ acceleration

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=-\frac{\gamma}{m}\frac{d\phi}{dt}
\end{equation}
since the gravity force $\vec{F}=m\vec{g}$ can be decomposed in $F_{//}$ (that balances the tension) and $F_\perp=mg\sin\theta$ and so there isn't a component of $F$ along $\phi$.
However using the lagrangian formalism for the spherical pendulum the equations are (assuming $\gamma=0$)

\begin{cases}
  \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=\sin\theta\cos\theta(\frac{d\phi}{dt})^2-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta\\
  \frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=-2\frac{d\phi}{dt}\cdot\frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\\
\end{cases}
and so I don't understand where the error of my procedure is.

Comment: It seems your equation just describes a 2D pendulum, not a spherical pendulum? what about the centripedal force?